# python writing to file exception occurs

Tags: python

"string indices must be integers" error occurs when using the code below.

```
global general_keys
general_keys = dict()
all_keys = {'activity': 'ins','install': 'all','aws.a': 'data', 'aws.b': 'data1', 'aws.c': 'data2'} 
general_key_array = ['install','db_manager', 'aws.']  

for key in general_key_array:
    for s in all_keys:
        if s.startswith(key):
            general_keys.update(dict(filter(lambda item: s in item[0], all_keys.items())))
```

file write section:

```
f.write("{0}{1}{2}".format("install=", general_keys['install']['install'], "\n"))
f.write("{0}{1}{2}".format("database_management_user=", general_keys['db_manager']['db_manager'], "\n"))
for key, value in general_keys['aws.'].items():
    f.write("{0}{1}{2}{3}".format(key, "=", value, "\n"))
```

expected output:

```
install=all
aws.a=data
aws.b=data1
aws.c=data2
```

[image]

Comment: "string indices must be integers" this is the only error I get. and it comes from a exception

Comment: The values in `general_keys` are strings, not dictionaries. So `general_keys['install']['install']` should just be `general_keys['install']`

Comment: You seem to think you're creating nested dictionaries. Print `general_keys()` and you'll see that you're not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not creating nested dictionaries. The value of `general_keys` you're creating is:

```
{'install': 'all', 'aws.a': 'data', 'aws.b': 'data1', 'aws.c': 'data2'}
```

To create the nested dictionaries you want, use.

```
from collections import defaultdict

general_keys = defaultdict(dict)
all_keys = {'activity': 'ins','install': 'all','aws.a': 'data', 'aws.b': 'data1', 'aws.c': 'data2'} 
general_key_array = ['install','db_manager', 'aws.']  

for key1 in general_key_array:
    for key2, value in all_keys.items():
        if key2.startswith(key1):
            general_keys[key1][key2] = value

print(dict(general_keys))
```

Output:

```
{
    'install': {'install': 'all'}, 
    'aws.': {'aws.a': 'data', 'aws.b': 'data1', 'aws.c': 'data2'}
}
```

Comment: Thanks it helped.